# Why is $\frac{0.5}{ \cos^2(30)} = \frac{\tan(30)}{\cos(30)} $, but $\frac{0.5}{ \cos^2(13) } \neq \frac{\tan(13)}{\cos(13)} $?

Tags: trigonometry

Is just it a coincidence that
$$\frac{0.5}{ \cos^2(30)} = \frac{\tan(30)}{\cos(30)} $$
However
$$\frac{0.5}{ \cos^2(13) } \neq \frac{\tan(13)}{\cos(13)} $$
is not equal ? And if not does anyone know a reason why they just so happen to be equatable?

Answer (score 4):

It's simply because $\sin(30^\circ)=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\tan(30)}{\cos(30)}=\frac{\frac{\sin(30)}{\cos(30)}}{\cos(30)}=\frac{\sin(30)}{\cos^2(30)}=\frac{0.5}{\cos^2(30)}$$since $\sin(30^\circ)=0.5$. The other equation would work if instead of $0.5$, you chose $\sin(13)\approx0.225$ as the numerator on the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the right side:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{0.5}{\cos^2(30^\circ)}&=\frac{\tan(30^\circ)}{\cos(30^\circ)}\\
&=\frac{\sin(30^\circ)}{\cos^2(30^\circ)}\\
&=\frac{0.5}{\cos^2(30^\circ)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If we use $x$ as a variable, we get the following:

$$\begin{align}
& \frac {0.5}{\cos^2x} = \frac {\tan x}{\cos x} \\
\implies& \frac {1}{2} \cos x = \cos^2 x \tan x\\
\implies& \cos x \tan x\ = \frac {1}{2} \\
\implies& \cos x \frac {\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac {1}{2}\\
\implies&  \sin x\ = \frac {1}{2}\
\end{align}$$

Thus the only solutions to the above equation are $x = 30^\circ \pm 360^\circ k$ or $x = 150^\circ \pm 360^\circ k$ where $k$ is any natural number.